# Can tbats forecast partial years

Tags: r, forecasting, tbats

I have several years of daily data from August to December. I read that I can use
`tbats` from the forecast package. Each year has approximately 153 days but sometimes
it has less. I am using the code below. Is this correct? I am trying to predict for the
next 1224 days (8 years) but I am getting a straight line for the predictions.

```
library(forecast)

head(creek) 
creek <- creek[,c(1,2)]
y <- msts(creek$Mean, seasonal.periods=c(7,153))
fit <- tbats(y)
fit
fc <- forecast(fit, h = 1224) ;fc
plot(fc)
autoplot(fc)
```

Data is here: https://login.filesanywhere.com/fs/v.aspx?v=8c6d638c60606fa66d9d

Answer (score 4):

TBATS models seasonality in the data with periods equal to the seasonal periods specified. If your data is not periodic, then it's not going to find the seasonal patterns, and may just settle for a simple model with no seasonality. That is what appears to have happened here.

When you create the `msts` object, all the date information is lost, so there is no way it can tell what is a full year or a partial year. It just looks for periodicities of length 7 and 153, but can't find them.

Comment: Thanks, will try Arima maybe?